# RN webrtc - Remote stream does not always display according to Wifi or mobile network

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webrtc

I’m building a video-call app in react native with react-native-webrtc package and I’m facing some problems when I run the app. Here is the situation (all the code used is below). To test my code, I run it on two devices (one android smartphone and one android tablet). Let’s name those “Client 1” and “Client 2”, Client 1 been the one who join a room and wait for Client 2. When Client 2 joins the room, he starts sending ice-candidate and offer to Client 1 who responds with answer. After that they share their stream and see each other’s camera. For connecting the clients, I use a NodeJS server deployed on Heroku on which clients connect through socket io. There are no problems with the connection to the server.

That’s what I want to do. However, it doesn’t succeed all the times. When the two devices are connected to the same wifi, each device can play the role of Client 1 and Client 2. But problems come when they are not on the same wifi or if one device is connected through mobile network. Here are the situation. I tried to be as exhaustive as possible to make you see where the problems come.
When I write “It works”, it means that both clients are connected through WebRTC and can see their local stream and remote stream. When I write “it fails”, the clients are not connected and can not see the remote stream.

1. If tablet (on wifi) = Client 1 and smartphone (on mobile network 4G) = Client 2 ==> it works
2. If smartphone (on mobile network 4G) = Client 1 and tablet (on wifi) = Client 2 ==> if fails
3. If tablet (on wifi 1) = Client 1 (or Client 2) and smartphone (on
   wifi 1) = Client 2 (or Client 1) ==> it works
4. If tablet (on wifi 1) = Client 1 and smartphone (on wifi 2) = Client 2 ==> it works
5. If tablet (on wifi 1) = Client 2 and smartphone (on wifi 2) = Client 1 ==> it fails

I already searched on Google, on stackoverfow and on [this forum](https://react-native-webrtc.discourse.group). I see that some people had the same problem and resolved it by adding a TURN server but I did it (after signing up on numb) and it’s not working for me:

```
const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: [
    {urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
    {
      url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
      credential: '************',
      username: '***********@***',
    },
  ],  
});
```

This is really weird because even if it fails, I manage to receive the remoteStream and compute the remoteStream.toURL() so I don’t understand why I can’t display the stream.

Here is the react native code:

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button, StyleSheet, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import FormButton from '../components/FormButton';
import {RTCPeerConnection, RTCView, mediaDevices, RTCIceCandidate, RTCSessionDescription} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default function VideoCallScreen({navigation}) {
  const [localStreamCached, setLocalStreamCached] = React.useState();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = React.useState();

  const roomID = "*****************";
  let localStream;
  const peerRef = useRef();
  const socketRef = useRef();

  // TMP const pour les afficher dans le DOM et avoir plus facile à comprendre comment tous les messages sont transmis
  const [copySocket, setCopySocket] = useState("");
  const [whichClient, setWhichClient] = useState("");
  const [hasAnyoneInRoomForClient1, setHasAnyoneInRoomForClient1] = useState(false);
  const [hasAnyoneInRoomForClient2, setHasAnyoneInRoomForClient2] = useState(false);
  const [otherUser, setOtherUser] = useState("");
  const [userJoined, setUserJoined] = useState("");

  // Peer connection
  const [receivedOfferFrom, setReceivedOfferFrom] = useState("");
  const [receivedAnswerFrom, setReceivedAnswerFrom] = useState("");
  const [receivedIceCandidate, setReceivedIceCandidate] = useState("");

  
  useEffect(() => {
    // ---------------------
    // Starting local stream
    // ---------------------
    startLocalStream();

    // -----------------
    // SOCKET CONNECTION
    // -----------------
    socketRef.current = io("https://*********.herokuapp.com", {transports: ['websocket']});

    socketRef.current.on("connect", () => {
      setCopySocket(socketRef.current.id);
      console.log("CONNECTION : ", socketRef.current.id);
      console.log(socketRef.current.id, " emit join room to server");
      socketRef.current.emit("join room", roomID);

      socketRef.current.on("other user", userID => {
        setWhichClient("Client 2");
        console.log(" Client 2: (", socketRef.current.id, ") : other user in the room = ", userID);
        setHasAnyoneInRoomForClient2(true);
        setOtherUser(userID);
        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Peer configuration: ice candidate & offer sending
        // -------------------------------------------------
        peerRef.current = peerConfiguration(userID, "Client 2");
      })

      socketRef.current.on("user joined", userID => {
        setWhichClient("Client 1");
        console.log("Client 1 : (", socketRef.current.id, ") : user joined the room = ", userID);
        setHasAnyoneInRoomForClient1(true);
        setUserJoined(userID);
      })

      // Réception de l'ice candidate du socket avec lequel on veut se connecter
      socketRef.current.on("ice-candidate", incoming => {
        handleReceivedIceCandidate(incoming, "Client 1");
      });

      // Réception de l'offre envoyée par l'autre pair
      socketRef.current.on("offer", incoming => {
        console.log("Client 1 : received offer from ", incoming.caller);
        handleReceiveOffer(incoming, "Client 1");
      });

      // Réception de la réponse que l'autre pair nous a envoyée après avoir reçu l'offre envoyée par le socket
      socketRef.current.on("answer", incoming => {
        console.log("Client 2 : received answer from ", incoming.caller);
        handleAnswer(incoming, "Client 2");
      });

    });

    socketRef.current.on('connect_error', (err) => {
      console.log("ERROR connection: ", err);
    })

    socketRef.current.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Disconnected Socket");
    })

  }, []);

      const handleReceivedIceCandidate = (incomingIceCandidate, clientNb) => {
        console.log(clientNb, " : received ice-candidate");
        setReceivedIceCandidate(incomingIceCandidate.candidate);
        const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(incomingIceCandidate);
        try {
          peerRef.current.addIceCandidate(candidate);
          console.log(clientNb, " : add ice candidate");
        } catch(e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }

    const handleReceiveOffer = (incoming, clientNb) => {

    setReceivedOfferFrom(incoming.caller);
    peerRef.current = peerConfiguration(null, clientNb);
    const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(incoming.sdp);
    peerRef.current.setRemoteDescription(desc)
    .then(() => {
      return peerRef.current.createAnswer();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error("Erreur 1: ", err))
    .then(answer => {
      return peerRef.current.setLocalDescription(answer);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error("Erreur 2: ", err))
    .then(() => {
      const payload = {
        target: incoming.caller,
        caller: socketRef.current.id,
        sdp: peerRef.current.localDescription
      }
      socketRef.current.emit("answer", payload);
      console.log(clientNb, " : emit answer to ", incoming.caller);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error("Erreur 3: ", err))
    }

    const handleAnswer = (incomingAnswer, clientNb) => {

     setReceivedAnswerFrom(incomingAnswer.caller);
     const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(incomingAnswer.sdp);
     peerRef.current.setRemoteDescription(desc)
     .catch(e => console.error("Erreur handle answer : ", e));
     console.log(clientNb, " : set remote description");
    }

    const startLocalStream = async () => {

    // isFront will determine if the initial camera should face user or environment
    const isFront = true;
    const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

    const facing = isFront ? 'front' : 'environment';
    const videoSourceId = devices.find(device => device.kind === 'videoinput' && device.facing === facing);
    const facingMode = isFront ? 'user' : 'environment';
    const constraints = {
      audio: true,
      video: {
        mandatory: {
          minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
          minHeight: 300,
          minFrameRate: 30,
        },
        facingMode,
        optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
      },
    };
    const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    localStream = newStream;
    setLocalStreamCached(newStream);
  };
  
  const peerConfiguration = (userID, clientNb) => {
    console.log(clientNb, " creates its RTCPeerConnection");
    const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
        {
          url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
          credential: '************',
          username: '***********@***',
        },
      ],  
    });

    // Ajout du stream local dans le RTCPeerConnection
    peer.addStream(localStream);
    console.log(clientNb, " : add local stream");

    // Ajout du stream remote
    peer.onaddstream = function (e){
      if (e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream){
        console.log(clientNb, " : add remote stream whose url = ", e.stream.toURL());
        setRemoteStream(e.stream);
      }
    };

    peer.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      // Création et envoi de l'offre
      console.log("current peerRef = ", peerRef.current);
      peer.createOffer()
        .then(offer => {
          return peer.setLocalDescription(offer)
          .then(() => {
            const payload = {
              target: userID,
              caller: socketRef.current.id,
              sdp: peerRef.current.localDescription
            };
            console.log(clientNb, " : emit offer to ", userID);
            socketRef.current.emit("offer", payload);
          })
          .catch(error => console.error("ERROR set local description", error));
        })
        .catch(error => console.error("ERROR create offer: ", error));
    };

    // Envoi de l'ice candidate
    peer.onicecandidate = function (e) {
      if (userID !== null){
        if (e.candidate) {
          const payload = {
            target: userID,
            candidate: e.candidate,
          }
          console.log(clientNb, " : emit ice-candidate to ", userID);
          socketRef.current.emit("ice-candidate", payload);
        } else {
          console.log(clientNb, " : all ice candidates sent");
        }
      }
    }

    peer.onicecandidateerror = error => {
      console.error("ERROR ice candidate: ", error);
    }

    peer.oniceconnectionstatechange = (val) => {
      console.log("oniceconnectionstatechange : ", val);
    }

    peer.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
      console.log(peer.connectionState);
      if(peer.connectionState === "connected") {
        console.log("PEERS CONNECTED");
      }
    }

    return peer;
  }

  const disconnectSocket = () => {
    socketRef.current.disconnect();
    navigation.navigate("Contact");
  }

return(
    <>
      <Text>Test socket</Text>
      <FormButton buttonTitle="Disconnect" onPress={() => disconnectSocket()}/>
      {copySocket !== "" && (
        <>
          <Text>ID socket : {copySocket}</Text>
          <Text>{whichClient}</Text>
        </>
      )}

      {/*Client 1*/}
      {whichClient === "Client 1" && (
        <>
          {hasAnyoneInRoomForClient1 == false && (
            <Text>No one is in the room for now, Client 1.</Text>
          )}
          {hasAnyoneInRoomForClient1 == true && (
            <Text>User joined: {userJoined}</Text>
          )}
        </>
      )}

      {/*Client 2*/}
      {whichClient === "Client 2" && (
        <>
          {hasAnyoneInRoomForClient2 == false && (
            <Text>No one is in the room for now, Client 2.</Text>
          )}
          {hasAnyoneInRoomForClient2 == true && (
            <Text>Other user : {otherUser}</Text>
          )}
        </>
      )}

      {receivedOfferFrom !== "" && (
        <Text>Offer received from : {receivedOfferFrom}</Text>
      )}
      {receivedIceCandidate !== "" && (
        <Text>Received candidate : {receivedIceCandidate}</Text>
      )}

      <View style={styles.rtcview}>
        <RTCView style={styles.rtc} streamURL={localStreamCached && localStreamCached.toURL()}/>
        {remoteStream && (
          <>
            <Text>{remoteStream.toURL()}</Text>
            <RTCView style={styles.rtc} streamURL = {remoteStream.toURL()}/>
          </>
        )}
      </View>
    </>
   )
 }
```

Here are the logs for the point 4 above.

**Client A (tablet on wifi 1) logs:**

[Part one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sbEj.png)

[Part two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWfvd.png)

**Client 2 (smartphjone on wifi 2) logs:**

[Part one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFTqC.jpg)

[Part two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMb6D.jpg)

And here are the logs for the point 5 above.
**Client 1 (smartphone on wifi 2) logs:**

[Part one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfUbb.jpg)

[Part two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Big20.jpg)

**Client 2 (tablet on wifi 1) logs:**

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x746.png)

The error **Failed to set local offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveRemoteOffer** comes everytime I run the app, whether it works or not. It comes from the onnegotiationneeded event but I don’t know why. I guess it’s not the problem I’m looking but if you know how to resolve it, go ahead!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess the problem lies in the firewall of the different peers. Because if you are connecting both peers on the same network, there is no firewall between them. But when you have to peers in different networks, then the firewall blocks the request or the NAT translation confuses the system. I've also tried to add an TURN to the configuration but it is also not working for me. Same problem and unsolved but this link helps for the understanding. [https://webrtchacks.com/an-intro-to-webrtcs-natfirewall-problem/](https://webrtchacks.com/an-intro-to-webrtcs-natfirewall-problem/)

Comment: @Jérôme Maquoi   Can you please share your server-side code.  my code is failing to set remote sdp